# Redirect to another page preserving query data and also SEO traffic information

Tags: php, redirect

I want to redirect from   `old.php?id=$post_id` to `new.php?id=$post_id` I do not want to lose any traffic from search engines etc.

So it will be `domain/old.php=1` to `domain/new.php=1`

Any help? I do not know much php programming.

with htacces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traffic is related to how your SEO is managed.

To redirect in PHP, you should use `header` function.

```
header('Location: new.php?id=' . $_GET['id']);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: In order not to affect 'traffic count' is better also to define this header : `header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); `

Comment: Its doesnt work! redirects only the name not the id of the article

Comment: Maybe you could give us a little more details?

Comment: the new url is new.php?id=1  the old is old.php?id=1 so when someone visits the old.php?=1 must redirects to new.php?id=1

Comment: I made a mistake in my code, I edited it. It's $_GET['id'] not $_GET['post_id']. If you do not know $_GET and $_POST variables, you should read manual to know what it is doing. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: It works! i use the header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header('Location: www.domain.com/new.php?id=' . $_GET['id']);

Comment: I need to hire someone for some mods in php